# PHPUnit3.6 with Ant Alternative for --log-pmd,--log-metrics?

Tags: php, zend-framework, ant, phpunit

does anyone know the alternative for --log-pmd,--log-metrics?

```
<arg line="--colors --coverage-html ${basedir}/build/report
             --log-junit ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.xml 
             --log-pmd ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.pmd.xml
             --log-metrics ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.metrics.xml
             --coverage-clover ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.coverage.xml 
             AllTests.php"/>
```

in phpunit 3.6 does not have --log-pmd,--log-metrics commands please anyone tell how do i write these command in 3.6 phpunit version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### PHPUnit 3.6 does not have the functionally behind those switches anymore.

`--log-pmd` was removed because of the way more useful and more powerful project

[**`PHPMD - PHP Mess Detector`**](http://phpmd.org/) that you can use standalone without phpunit

---

While `--log-metrics` was removed and for all things metrics you want to turn to the

[**`PHP_Depend software analyzer and metric tool.`**](http://pdepend.org/)

---

For basic metrics and a project size overview (loc, nloc, cc, avg. cc/method) there is the [**`phploc`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc) command line tool.

#### Documentation on how to use those tools (with ant)

can be found over at [**`jenkins-php.org`**](http://jenkins-php.org). Looking at the build.xml you will see how to use those to generate CLI and xml output.

Comment: ... 'that you can use standalone without phpunit'. Thought that. Now I'm sure. Thanks! :)